# css: trouble positioning elements with display:flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a **h1** and a **p** inside a **div** with **display:flex**.
The two are positioned side by side, but they have to be under each other.
It is about the elements with class jktitre  and class jktxt inside (div)jkpage.
jkpage div is flex with jksidebar (side by side)

I did not expect that the text elements somehow inherit the flex property. Or something like that.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jkheader"></div>
    <div class="jknavbar"></div>
    <div class="jkrow">
        <div class="jkpage">
            <h1 class="jktitre">BLABLABLA</h1>
            <p class="jktxt">jeoipfjn ehuwfojv ebowuinlj;hnjveohjej</p>
        </div>
        <div class="jksidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="jkfooter"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
  body{
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.jktitre{
    margin-left:5%;
    float:left;
    display: block;
}

.jktxt{
    margin-left:5%;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;

}

.jkrow{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
}

.jkheader{
    margin-top:20px;
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #2d18a4;
}

.jknavbar{
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.jkpage{
    height:400px;
    width:75%;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    display:flex;
}

.jksidebar{
    height:400px;
    width:25%;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    display:flex;
}

.jkfooter{
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `flex-direction: column` to the parent element to display them under each other. The default value for it is `row` which shows the child elements from left to right(Side by side)

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.jktitre {
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.jktxt {
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.jkrow {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.jkheader {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2d18a4;
}
.jknavbar {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
.jkpage {
  height: 400px;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.jksidebar {
  height: 400px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  display: flex;
}
.jkfooter {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="jkheader"></div>
  <div class="jknavbar"></div>
  <div class="jkrow">
    <div class="jkpage">
      <h1 class="jktitre">BLABLABLA</h1>
      <p class="jktxt">jeoipfjn ehuwfojv ebowuinlj;hnjveohjej</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jksidebar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="jkfooter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I would never have found that without searching for a long time. :)

Comment: No problem, Joris. Glad it helped! :)